# How to get part of string from regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

For example, I have string with range of earnings:

```
5 000-10 000 USD
```

and i want to extract from that string minimum and maximum value.
I prepared regexes, for exalmple for first value:

```
[0-9| ]*-
```

And now i do not know how to get that part of string.
I tried with pattern and matcher like:

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\([A-Z|a-z]+");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
            String employmentType = matcher.group(0);
```

But I am getting null

Comment: You are getting null because your expression does not contain any capturing groups.  A capturing group starts with `(` and ends with `)`.  Do not escape either parenthesis with backslashes, as that turns the following character into a literal character which will not be treated as a special regex character at all.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative regex:

```
"(\\d[\\s\\d]*?)-(\\d[\\s\\d]*?)\\sUSD"
```

Regex in context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "5 000-10 000 USD";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\d[\\s\\d]*?)-(\\d[\\s\\d]*?)\\sUSD").matcher(input);
    if(matcher.find()) {
        String minValue = matcher.group(1);
        String maxValue = matcher.group(2);
        System.out.printf("Min: %s, max: %s%n", minValue, maxValue);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Min: 5 000, max: 10 000
```

Other alternative, Alt. 2:

```
"\\d[\\s\\d]*?(?=-|\\sUSD)"
```

Alt. 2 regex in context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "5 000-10 000 USD";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d[\\s\\d]*?(?=-|\\sUSD)").matcher(input);
    List<String> minAndMaxValueList = new ArrayList<>(2) ;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        minAndMaxValueList.add(matcher.group(0));
    }

    System.out.printf("Min value: %s. Max value: %s%n", minAndMaxValueList.get(0), minAndMaxValueList.get(1));
}
```

Alt. 2 output:

```
Min value: 5 000. Max value: 10 000
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use space to split the string values , you can try this

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\s]+");
String[] result = p.split(text);
```

Comment: `[\\s]+` is exactly the same as `\\s+`.  Not that it matters, in this case;  Lulex wants `5 000` and `10 000` to be read as the values 5,000 and 10,000, so splitting on whitespace will not address the problem.

Comment: Oops, read it again and you're right！ It may be easier to understand if the expected result is written in the question.